# Discrete mathematics question help

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

I need help with my discrete structure homework. 
Compute each of the following and simplify your answer.

i.  $\frac{(n-1)!}{ (n+1)!}$

ii. $\frac{n!}{(n-2)!}$

iii. $\frac{(n+2)!}{n!}$

I can't really conpute the value of this expression because I don't know how for example to express $(n-1)!$ in function of $n!$.

Comment: What you need to know is that $n!$ represents the product of all positive integers less than or equal to $n$ (*noting the special case of $0!$ which equals the empty product which is interpreted as $1$*).  This leads to $n! = (1\times 2\times 3\times \cdots \times (n-1)\times n) = (1\times 2\times 3\times \cdots \times (n-1))\times n = (n-1)!\times n$.  That is to say, you may "separate the last term of a factorial off" to deal with it separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case $n+1>n-1$ and so the fraction is not integer:
$$\frac{(n-1)!}{(n+1)!}=\frac{(n-1)!}{(n+1)\cdot n \cdot (n-1)!}=\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$$

In the second case, using the method described before we arrive at: $$\frac{n\cdot(n-1)\cdot(n-2)!}{(n-2)!}=n(n-1)$$

In the third case, as before: $$\frac{(n+2)\cdot(n+1)\cdot n!}{n!}=(n+2)(n+1)$$

From your comments, we have to compute:
$$\binom{n}{2}=\frac{n!}{2!\cdot(n-2)!}=\frac{n\cdot(n-1)}{2}$$

$$\binom{10}{6}=\frac{10!}{6!\cdot4!}=\frac{10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7}{4!}=210$$

$$\binom{n+2}{n}=\frac{(n+2)\cdot(n+1)\cdot n!}{2!\cdot n!}=\frac{(n+2)\cdot(n+1)}{2}$$

Comment: can u solve 2nd and 3rd also please?

Comment: Can you vote it up?

Comment: I did thank you

Comment: if possible can you also help me with these: Compute the following (n choose r) :      

i.     n choose 2

ii.   10 choose 6

iii.  n+2 choose n

Comment: I suggest you to open a new post because the answer can't stay in comments or editing the post.